# (Windows 10) Restart Without Updating in C++

Tags: c++, windows-10, restart

I need a way to restart my pc in C++ and do it in a way that Windows doesn't install updates on that restart. Is this possible?

I know you can do a restart using `system("shutdown -r -t 0");`

or `ExitWindowsEx( EWX_REBOOT | EWX_FORCE, SHTDN_REASON_FLAG_PLANNED )`

but both of these install updates while restarting. Any Ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is possible with Windows full stop, is it?

Comment: Yeah, I was just reading through that, it would be quite disappointing if this is impossible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, a solution that worked was going into "Services" application and disabling "Windows Updates". Then whenever I restart normally, it won't update.